issue of indexing by Schedule on Cloud instance
Team.
Have an issue:
Indexing by Schedule on Cloud instance doesn't work.
The log:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'catalog_product_attribute_cl__tmp66ddd5fec67630_04762276' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT MAX(id) as max, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM (SELECT `catalog_product_attribute_cl__tmp66ddd5fec67630_04762276`.* FROM `catalog_product_attribute_cl__tmp66ddd5fec67630_04762276` WHERE (`catalog_product_attribute_cl__tmp66ddd5fec67630_04762276`.`id` > '2') ORDER BY `catalog_product_attribute_cl__tmp66ddd5fec67630_04762276`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1000) AS `t`

As a result, I have to use it by Save.
Is anyone who faced it ? I would appreciate any idea.

The matter is:
Magento creates table using mariaDB memory, which doesn't work correctly in cloud.
Patch ACSD-58739 is creating tmp table inside MariaDB database instead of memory.
The issue is resolved.
